# Should Ubuntu Questions on U&L be smarter about deleted questions?

Tags: bug, chat

As those who regularily attend the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) may know, new questions posted on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) tagged [ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) are "featured" in the room by [Ubuntu Questions on U&L](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-45/ubuntu-questions-on-ul) shortly after they've been posted.

The problem is that the bot doesn't cater for already deleted questions (and this is a problem expecially for spam / rude or abusive questions).

For instance, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251107/know-more-about-beelite-obviously-best-weight-loss-product) spam question was featured after it was deleted:

[image: s1]

Should Ubuntu Questions on U&L be smarter about deleted questions?

Comment: Is it a coincidence that almost all spam is by Garcinia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spam post was deleted at 9:47:58, and [the chat post's timestamp](http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/26385582/history) is given as "9:47 AM". I guess it was a matter of seconds. I think we can let the bot off the hook, just this once.

Comment: Indeed, stating that the post was deleted already was an unfounded assumption. Then we're talking about seconds, since I clicked almost immediately after. I can't see the message's timestamp though, I get a "Page Not Found".

Comment: @kos you can see `9:47` in the screenshot. :P

Comment: I hoped the transcript would have reported the seconds, just to see by how much I was off. :D